# Uncaught ReferenceError: TodoList is not defined at evalmachine.<anonymous>:1:7

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, truffle, ganache

I've been following a tutorial for the past couple of days and I keep getting this error.

```
 todoList = await TodoList.deployed()
```

My contract is migrated to the blockchain but I cannot deploy it.

Comment: can you share all your js script?

Comment: what is the error you've got? This is the command you executed.

Answer (score 1):

Hi instead of `taskCount = await app.taskCount()`

write and run

```
taskCount = await todoList.taskCount()
```

and then,

```
 taskCount.toNumber()
```

we are doing this because truffle when retrieves a value it stores into BN(big number) format to convert it into a (number) we are using these lines.

[you can Check Code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUoU2.png)